# B1/B2 rejected twice for business purpose, implications and wait times

Tags: visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I was denied a B1/B2 visa twice in a span of one month for business purposes.

1st application was denied for the fact that my company was sending me for around 3 months.

2nd application i made for 3 weeks and that i guess raised suspicions and didnt go through as well, in both cases i received the standard 214b and the officer was suspecting i would be working, told me to apply for different category.

My profile is as follows
Male Indian living in singapore for last 6 years with an above average salary in the field of engineering, during my lifetime i have travelled to 20+ countries till now. I also work for a well reputed US firm. My Visa Application Center was also Singapore.

I wish to travel to US in the future maybe after a year for tourism, will the officer still be worried that i intend to work there, since I don’t plan to change my company for the next few years and it will always have its HQ in US, moreover going as a tourist will it still not be classified as change in circumstances, since this time i wont be having company letters. I know people earning way less than me also successfully managed to secure a US Visa, its very difficult for me to overcome this refusal.

Moreover i want to travel to Australia next month on a tourist visa, i have also been granted one in the past, will this record pose serious implications to all my visa applications in the future to any other countries especially to Australia since i have already planned my trip and will be applying for the visa now.

Or is it safe to assume my travelling days are over?

I have seen threads that say to change personal circumstances, i believe apart from age change and maybe salary change i have nothing to offer, since my travel history is pretty decent.

Can someone guide me?

Comment: No your travelling days are not over.  One country's refusal of a visa is not the end of everything. In regards to your business visa being denied, what activities did you intend to be doing for the three months/three weeks period? (That seems to be a very long time to be spending in meetings/trainings, which may be why the officer thought you intended to work.)

Comment: If you have no business connections to Australia or other countries you want to visit, your US refusal isn’t the end of the world. However, as the US shares biometric information with Canada, Australia, New Zealand and the United Kingdom, you should expect these to know about your refusals.

Comment: Thats glad to hear, only obtaining a US visa in the future will be a problem, since my job wont change so they always have a chance to suspect my activities as visit to HQ for work. I have heard that even after changing the situation it may not be enough

Comment: You *can* visit your employer's hq on business. You can do certain limited business related activities. You *cannot* work. (As the consular officer mentioned, you need a different class of visa, likely H1B, to actually work.) You could also apply for a tourist visa and do tourist things instead.